# What do RLPx and ÐΞV stand for?

Tags: rlpx

I'm curious about the origin of the RLPx protocol suite's name and the ÐΞV's name, but I cannot find information in the [official documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/%C3%90%CE%9EV-Technologies) and [RLPx documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md).

### RLPx

I read in a blog (not an official one without source, therefore I ask) that RLPx stand for **R**ecursive **L**enght **P**refix e**X**tended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### RLPx

It stands for RLP extended

### ÐΞV

It can be seen as a wordplay that resembles the word DEV (the abbreviation for Developers), where Ð is an ancient greek letter that is read "eth" (more details in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52330/%C3%90%CE%9Evp2p-dapps-why-is-it-in-%C3%90-not-d-any-special-significance-of-using-%C3%90)) and the greek letter Ξ ("Xi") is the symbol of Ethereum according to [this website](https://ethereumsymbol.com/).