# ÐΞVp2p / DApps - why is it in "Ð" not "D"? Any special significance of using Ð?

Tags: devp2p

ÐΞVp2p / DApps - why is it in "Ð" not "D"? Any special significance with using Ð instead of the normal D?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ð is [a letter from Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eth), pronounced *"eth"*.

So "Ðapp" could actually be pronounced *"eth-app"*, though I imagine most people pronounce the Ð as a hard *"d"* (for *dog*).

Ξ is the upper-case Greek letter, [Xi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi_(letter)). I don't know why this was chosen (someone else might).

Comment: amazing !! i wasn't aware of that. thanks @Richard

Answer (score 0):

You may see DApps spelled as ÐApps. The Ð character is the Latin character called "ETH," alluding to Ethereum. To display this character, use the Unicode codepoint 0xD0, or if necessary the HTML character entity eth (or decimal entity #208).